# Is there correct way to navigate in flutter through drawer?

Tags: flutter, flutter-drawer

I am newbie in Flutter. I want to ask is there correct way to navigate between screens through drawer? Because there is a problem with navigation stack.

```
|:-------:|
|-------|
|-------|
|-------|
|screen1|
```

for example if screen 1 has a navigation button and it is navigates to screen1 and it will be like this

```
|-------|
|-------|
|screen1|
|screen1|
|screen1|
```

i need something like replacement and make my navigation stack like first table

So, i tried pushName and this way https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-vi-navigation-drawer-flutter-1-0-3a05e09b0db9 but this give me another problem with "Could not find a generator for route RouteSettings"

Answer (score 1):

Try just using `Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder:(BuildContext context) => YourScreen()));`. It should work and it replaces the current screen.

Comment: `drawerButton(labelText: "Новости", onTap: () => Navigator.pushNamed(context, Routes.newsPage), ),` I tried this but same problem

Answer (score 1):

For a details of navigation  kindly read article

https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-push-pop-push-1bb718b13c31

Use pushReplacementNamed instead of pushNamed

```
drawerButton(
              labelText: "Новости",
              onTap: () => Navigator. pushNamed(context, Routes.newsPage),             
            ),
```

becomes

```
drawerButton(
              labelText: "Новости",
              onTap: () => Navigator. pushReplacementNamed(context, Routes.newsPage),
            ),
```